# How to get Azure Storage Account Key (connectionString) using azure .net sdk or fluent API?

Tags: c#, azure-sdk-.net, azure-fluent-api

I want get `Azure Storage Account Key (connectionString)` using azure `.NET SDK`  or fluent API.

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me what you try?

Comment: Stanley's answer is correct, please accept his answer to end this question. You just need to create an aad app to get the credential before using his code. You need [these packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8yTr.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
    var azure = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription(subscriptionID);

    var storageName = "<storage name>";
    var resourceGroup = "<storage resource group>";

    var keys = azure.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, storageName).GetKeys();
    
    var key1 = keys[0];
    var key2 = keys[1];

    var connStr1 = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + storageName + ";AccountKey="+ key1.Value + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    var connStr2 = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + storageName + ";AccountKey=" + key2.Value + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
```